# Same code, same database, different results on testing server and local server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My local environment and my testing environment are both connected to the same database engine (postgresql) and have the same Django settings.

In my TableA, I have some duplicate rows and I only want to get the ones that belong to "category_1" with distinct "field1" values. So I do:

```
result = TableA.objects.filter(category='category_1').distinct('field1').order_by('field1')
```

This creates the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("TableA"."field1") "TableA"."id", "TableA"."category", "TableA"."field1" 
FROM "TableA" 
WHERE "TableA"."category"= "category_1"
ORDER BY "TableA"."field1"
```

The result looks correct on the local, but when I test it on my testing server the result still includes the rows that have the same "field1" values.

What could possibly go wrong??

Comment: Either you didn't deployed you latest changes or Edit the question and show the local and testing database configuration.

Comment: Take a real hard look at the field1 values that you think are the same! For example, trailing spaces? "Il" vs "II"? Maybe in the shell, extract them into a list and then make a set out of the list. If the length of the set is the same as the length of the list, they really are all distinct!